# Call Java class method from JSP

Tags: java, class, jsp, methods

Need to call a Java method from a class to display a string in JSP

Tried calling the method using `<%apple.bite %>`

and also initiated a new instance, and the page import is correct on the top.

tried

```
apple a = new apple;
a.bite();
```

Comment: did you got any error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
<%@ page import="com.xx.ClassNameX" %>
```

Then call method from instance

```
<%
   new ClassNameX().method();
%>
```

Comment: The problem is that I am trying to call a class, run a program from a jsp. But the class has a public static void main String{} arg {  for its method. I need to run the program. but the method isnt defined simply to be called like the expression you wrote. Thats my problem.

Comment: In that case, can you move the logic inside main method to a new static method. then you can call ClassNameX.newMethodName()

Answer (score 0):

Actually the way that works, the answer that works for me is:`
Inside JSP

```
<%@page import="com.apple.bite"%>
<%
apple aApple = new apple();
apple.bite();

%>`
```